# where in an XCode project does it set "InfoPlist.strings" as the filename to use for locationalization?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, localization, info-plist

where in an XCode project does it set "InfoPlist.strings" as the filename to use for locationalization?

Just trying to understand how XCode pulls things together here.  For example to set the app name specifically I can change this in "AppName_plist-Info.plist", however if I go localization it seems it then has to be set via the "InfoPlist.strings" files.

I can see in XCode where it specifies the "AppName_plist-Info.plist" file name, in the Target/BuildSettings/Packaging information area, but I don't see mention of "InfoPlist.strings", so how does Xcode/IOS know to override what is in  "AppName_plist-Info.plist" based on what's in "InfoPlist.strings"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode doesn't really override the name, it creates localizations in your apps bundle. iOS will look for the name of the app in de localization folder to which the language of the system is set.

These files have pre-determent names, thus you can not set them.
All the localized files will be for example in `bundle.app\en.lproj` for english or `bundle.app\nl.lproj`for dutch.

Comment: so is it just the case XCode is hardwired to use what's in "AppName_plist-Info.plist", but then if there is a variable name in any localisation file that matches it uses this first?  Seems like it.

Comment: You can use `InfoPlist.strings` just fine for translating any supported string in to `AppName_plist-Info.plist`. the `AppName_plist-Info.plist` will become `info.plist` in your app bundle.