# xcode using Localizable.strings instead of InfoPlist.strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I recently localized my first app which did not initially work.  After much experimentation I discovered that it required a localized file Localizable.strings instead of the default InfoPlist.strings.

Is there any way to set Xcode to use the default, InfoPlist.strings?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you can according to the [iOS Developer Library - Localizing String Resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/StringsFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000005-SW1).  (emphasis mine)

> Resource files that contain localizable strings are referred to as strings files (with the deliberate extra 's' in the word "strings") because of their filename extension, which is .strings. You can create strings files manually or programmatically depending on your needs. The standard strings file format consists of one or more key-value pairs along with optional comments. The key and value in a given pair are strings of text enclosed in double quotation marks, separated by an equal sign, and terminated by a semicolon. **(You can also use a property list format for strings files. In such a case, the top-level node is a dictionary and each key-value pair of that dictionary is a string entry.)**

See also: [where in an XCode project does it set "InfoPlist.strings" as the filename to use for locationalization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253197/where-in-an-xcode-project-does-it-set-infoplist-strings-as-the-filename-to-use)